# chart range with variable using

Tags: excel, vba

Range in the following command is used draw the chart.

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Data_Alignment").Range("A1:C721,J1:H721")
```

I need to use range as a variable, when use command

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Data_Alignment").Range(rng1)
```

it gives error 1004 and donot generate required chart. Instead it selects all data from A to H and draw the chart

My code is

```
Sub ChartMain()
Dim b As Double '/ row1
Dim c As Double '/ row2
Dim rng1 As String
c = 721

For b = 1 To 10400 Step 721
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select     
    Let rng1 = "A" & b & ":C" & c & ",J" & b & ":H" & b
    TG_Chart rng1
Next b

End Sub

Sub TG_Chart(rng1)
    Sheets("Graphs").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.Parent.Left = 60
    ActiveChart.Parent.Top = 30
    ActiveChart.Parent.Height = 150
    ActiveChart.Parent.Width = 400
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(rng1)
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.ClearToMatchStyle
    ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 236
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisNone)
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryGridLinesNone)
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementLegendTop)
    ActiveChart.Legend.Select
    Selection.Width = 277.275
    Selection.Left = 6.362
    Selection.Width = 374.275
    b=b+721
End Sub
```

Please help me rectify the issue with my code

Comment: Are you trying to generate 14+ Charts? Your For Loop seems to be out of sync, it says step by 721 until b = 10400, which is 14.42 loops, this should be rectified, then you also add 721 to b in TG_Chart(rng1), when b is a local variable and it gets incremented under your For Loop in ChartMain...